# add progress bar to jquery ajax file upload

Tags: php, ajax, upload, progress-bar

hey there i am using ajax to upload images. the codes are as follows.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function()           { 
                       //$("#preview").html('');

                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
                     beforeSubmit:function(){ 

                    console.log('ttest');
                    $("#imageloadstatus").show();
                     $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
                     }, 
                    success:function(){ 
                    console.log('test');
                     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                     $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                    }, 
                    error:function(){ 
                    console.log('xtest');
                     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                    $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                    } }).submit();


            });
        }); 
</script>

<style>

body
{
font-family:arial;
}

#preview
{
color:#cc0000;
font-size:12px
}
.imgList 
{
max-height:150px;
margin-left:5px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;    
float:left; 
}

</style>
<body>

<div>

<div id='preview'>
</div>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaxImageUpload.php' style="clear:both">
<h1>Upload your images</h1> 
<div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
<div id='imageloadbutton'>
<input type="file" name="photos[]" id="photoimg" multiple />
</div>
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the `ajaxImageUpload.php`

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

$session_id='1'; //$session id
define ("MAX_SIZE","9000"); 
function getExtension($str)
{
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
}


$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{

    $uploaddir = "uploads/"; //a directory inside
    foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
        $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
        //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
          $ext = getExtension($filename);
          $ext = strtolower($ext);

         if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
         {
           if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
           {
           $image_name=time().$filename;
           echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>";
           $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;

           move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname);


           }
           else
           {
            echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';

           }

          }
          else
         { 
            echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';

         }

     }
}
echo $uploaddir.$image_name;
?>
```

right now it displays an animated gif while it uploads the images. what i want to do is remove the gif and replace it with a progress bar but i have no clue how to do this and i am on a time schedule. could anyone please tell me how to do this. thanks!

Comment: Use a library: **[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)** or **http://plupload.com/**. Creating the feedback mechanism for a progress bar requires a little more work than changing the gif alone. Since you're on a time schedule and I don't think anyone here is just gonna do it for you, I suggest, use a library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PHP code for processing the upload does not run until the entire file is uploaded, so it is not possible for you detect how much of the file has been uploaded in that script.

Generally you find upload progress bars built into a browser or some "client-side" program like a Flash application that can control that level of transfer.

For a strict PHP and Javascript implementation there are some workarounds that are fragile and a lot of work and are not very common (hence why you are asking here). There are some jQuery plugins that exist that can do this http://plugins.jquery.com/uploadfile/.

Comment: not write information you can detect chunk of file uploaded